# Joomla 2.5 cant use $this in helper file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have created a component and a plugin in joomla 2.5 and there is a `Helper` file in the component which will have many useful functions and I plan to call one of its function which then calls another function in the helper by this code:

```
$this->getinformation();
```

and it gives me this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method
```

My questions are:

- Why can't I call a function in a helper in Joomla?
- How can I call a function inside helper class?
- Is there any class structure which i missed in this code?

Comment: First off in order to use $this your helper file needs to be a class.  Is it a a class or just a collection of functions.  What does your helper file look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Helper files are typically called statically and not using $this

First create your helper file and add methods like this:

```
Class myHelper {

    //This method can call other methods
    public static function myMethod($var) {

        //Call other method inside this class like this:
        self::myOtherMethod($var);

    }

    //This method is called by myMethod()
    public static function myOtherMethod($var) {

        //Put some code here

    }

}
```

Simply include the helper file like this in the documents that you would to use it:

```
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/my_helper.php';
```

Then use it like this:

```
myHelper::myMethod($var);
```

or

```
myHelper::myOtherMethod($var);
```

Comment: That was static function kind of problem , I create a instance of the class and issue gone . it happen before your answer but thank you anyway .

Comment: Shouldn't be `self::myOtherMethod($var);` instead of `self:myOtherMethod($var);` ?

Comment: Yes it should. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the helper file and call the function using the classname

Add the following line in the plugin or component:

```
jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.folder' );
require_once JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_xxxx/helper.php';

classname::functionname();
```

OR

If you are working on the same helper file means then call like this

```
classname::functionname();
```

Comment: This will work if he has set up his class correctly and defined them as static functions.